# Android apps not compatible between roms

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, custom-roms

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 with CM10, I was testing SlimRom and notice that some applications that I bought on PlayStore showed the message "This app is not compatible with your device". It's the same device with different rom.

Any ideas about why this happen?

thanks!

Comment: I've had that before, I think it has something to do with how the device was named on the build.prop. I had a device that runs on ICS before, I changed rom to another ICS and one of my apps showed incompatible on the Play Store. I installed the app from a [backup copy](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup&hl=en) and it ran without problems.

Comment: @ShedoSurashu This is the correct answer, why not post it as such?

Comment: Your best bet is to back up your apps prior to switching ROMs so you can install the app from your local backup and not rely on the Play Store.  You can also modify your build.prop to fool the Play Store.

Comment: Done! @Matt. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had that before, I think it has something to do with how the device was named on the build.prop. I had a device that runs on ICS before, I changed rom to another ICS and one of my apps showed incompatible on the Play Store. I installed the app from a [backup copy](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup&hl=en) and it ran without problems.